# Windows 7 Hardware Disconnect/Reconnect noise when monitor is in sleep - make it stop

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, audio, external-display

Whenever I plug either of two Windows 7 laptops into my Planar 27" monitor, I get a constant hardware disconnect/reconnect sound when the monitor goes to sleep. It drives me absolutely insane, so I shut off my speakers.

I do NOT want this. However, I want the disconnect/reconnect sounds for all my other devices, so the "just disable the sounds" 'fix' is unacceptable.

I have a suspicion that the cause is the speakers / audio playback device that's in the monitor over the HDMI cable, but I also don't want to downgrade my connection to an RGB cable. What better solutions are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With the monitor connected, type `manage audio devices` in the Start Menu search box
2. Right-click inside the **Playback** tab and make sure both the following options are checked:

   [image]
3. Now if the offending device shows up, see if you can right-click and **Disable** it

Another place to check for the device would be in the **Device Manager**.

You can also check your sound card's (advanced) settings and see if there's any way to disable only HDMI audio and leave the video intact.

Comment: This did seem to work, although my ideal solution would leave it enabled while suppressing the noise for the one device.